# Cannot access pdf files in resources folder

Tags: spring, pdf, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, web

i have a web app where i put some pdf files in the resources folder that are rendered to users when they click a download button, this is how i read the file

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextLoader();
File f = new File(classloader.getResource("pdf/report.pdf").getFile);
```

Then i render the file within a response, this works fine when i run it in eclipse.

But once i package it into a war file and deploy it using apache tomcat manager, i cannot access the file anymore it shows me a 500 ERROR that the specified access file is inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you need to get stream for the resource and serve response from that resource and not from the file. Classloader has function getResourceAsStream which should work with same parameter your are passing to getResource

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextLoader();
InputStream stream = classloader.getResourceAsStream("pdf/report.pdf")
// Copy resource stream to servlet response e.g. using Apache IOUTils
IOUtils.copy(stream, <servelet response stream>)
// Don't forget to close stream
```

Eclipse most like is resolving local file path which may not work in web applications environment in same way.

Answer (score -1):

open your war file and check manually into "/WEB-INF/classes/" folder your file is exist into this folder or not.